# How to choose auto random slider in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am working on ionic 2.
I have many slider in a array list, which is being auto slide.
I need to choose random slide from that list, How I can?

```
*****************************************************
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68
******************************************************
```

Code I have as-
mypage.html--

```
<ion-slides #mySlider  [options]="mySlideOptions">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let quote of slides">
    <div class="myslider">
        <div class="quote-container" [innerHTML]="quote.title"></div>
        <div [innerHTML]="quote.author" ></div>
     </div>
   </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

page.ts--

```
slides: Slide[];
this.slides = [
      {id: 1,  author: "-Sanjay",     title: "my text goes here."},
      {id: 2,  author: "-Sanjay",     title: "my text goes here"},
      {id: 3,  author: "-Sanjay",     title: "my text goes here"},
      {id: 4,  author: "-Sanjay",     title: "my text goes here"}]
```

Fonction of slider-

```
// quotes slider
  mySlideOptions = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    loop: true,
    effect: 'fade',
    fade: {crossFade:true},
    autoplay:2700,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true,
    direction:"horizontal",
    speed:4000,
    nextButton: ".pause-me",
    prevButton: ".swiper-button-prev" 
  };
```

But not being slide randomly, any help?

Comment: Your question is not clear, you want to display the image in a random order?

Comment: yes, something like that, but all images must be in array list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method below will autoslide your slides, whenever a slide changed, a new (random) slide will come. The random method uses your slideslist's length to calculate a random index (between 0 and max list length - 1).

**ts**

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

class MyPage {
   @ViewChild('mySlider') slider: Slides;


   ....

   getRandomIndex(): number {
     // uses your list.length to get a random value within the range
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.slides.length)
   }

   newSlide() {
     this.slider.slideTo(this.getRandomIndex(),500)
   }
}
```

**html**

`<ion-slides #mySlider (ionDidChange)="newSlide()" ........>`

All information in this answer has been retrieved from [the ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/)